# Calling a Function Several Times or Creating a Variable

Tags: java, function, variables

First, I would like to create the scenario and explain the question. For example I have a function which returns an integer:

```
int function(){  
    return 5;
}
```

and I would like to print this value which is returned by the function a few times. Now this part popped-up the question:

Should I call the function for each time

```
   System.out.print("My lucky number is " + function());
   System.out.print("When I was "+function()+" years old");
   .
   .
   .
```

or should I store the return value in a variable to use it?

```
   int x = function();
   System.out.print("My lucky number is " + x);
   System.out.print("When I was "+x+" years old");
   .
   .
   .
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. In this case they're functionally equivalent but they mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

- If there is a side effect in calling `function()` (e.g. it prints something out, increments a variable etc), you have to call it each time.
- If there are no side effects, but it's expensive to call (e.g. it does some complex calculation), you might be wise to store it in a variable.
- Otherwise, it's simply a matter of readability/preference.

Answer (score 1):

So both variants work and are okay, in general, the best practice would be to call the function once and store it in x.  That would lower runtime and is easier to read. In this case, it wouldn't change your time complexity but it would make it more readable and maintainable.

Long story short, it really comes down to readability/maintainability and runtime.  And in this specific case readability.  There's a lot of resources on this but here is a quick link to one

https://blog.goyello.com/2013/01/21/top-9-principles-clean-code/